# Nginx : Error_log and Access_log max size

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

i need to define max size of error_log and error_access in Nginx.conf.
i found that error_log has size of 400gb
for moment my configuration is pretty basic `error_log  /home/ubuntu/logs/nginx-logs/error.log` 
is there a way to specify  this ?

Comment: Do you ever heard about logs rotation? Read [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/427144/how-to-limit-nginx-access-log-file-size-and-compress) Q/A for example.

Comment: is the rotation can be applied for error_log too or just access_log  ?

Comment: Actually, rotation can be applied to any set of files. For example, from one of my servers `/etc/logrotate.d/nginx` file contents is `/var/log/nginx/*.log /home/*/logs/nginx*log { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used logs Rotation to solve the issue :
Answered by [Ivan Shatsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7121513/ivan-shatsky)